# how to name a file as (vaiable).jpg in qrcode

Tags: python, qr-code

```py
import qrcode

n = input(str("Please enter the link of video: " ))

z = input("Please enter the question number: " )

img = qrcode.make(n)

img.save(z)
```

A file saved without any extension.  For example, if `z == 1`, then
it is saved as `1` instead of `1.jpg`.

If I add

```py
img.save(z.jpg) or (z."jpg")
```

it gives a syntax error.

What can I do to make it save it as `1.jpg`?

Answer (score 2):

Strings can be concatenated with the plus sign.

```
img.save(z + ".png")
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a qr directory and an image as `img` with qr,

```
path = os.path.join("qr", f"{any_variable}.png")
img.save(path)
```